# Organising WebApi Controllers under a single root folder and routing to them

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-core-routing

### Background

In most `MVC` and `WebApi` applications we typically see the following structure:

```
/Controllers
  HomeController.cs
/Models
```

Typically this is generated from the MVC template.

This will then generate a route mapping in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

### Added Complexity

Our web applications really start growing in complexity when we add other parts to it like custom ActionResults, [Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1), and Areas amongst other things.  All of a sudden the top level folder can feel a little cluttered even if it is organised nicely.

### Question

Typically when we add an `Area` out of the box, a new top level folder named Areas is created.

My preference would be to have a project folder with all controller related functionality moved to it, like an api folder.

For example:

```
/api
  /Home
    /Controllers
      HomeController.cs
    /Models
  /SomeArea1
    /Controllers
    /Models
```

The problem here is now you need to change route configuration and include api in the route - which I *DO NOT* want.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areaRoute",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Is it possible to have the above folder structure in the project and have a route to it like following?

```
http://localhost/ maps to /api/Home 
http://localhost/customer maps to /api/Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can route something like done in below code

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("blog", "blog/{*article}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Article" });
   routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Please check the documentation here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#route-names

Comment: But that would mean naming every controller route?

Comment: There was a link underneath which talks about namespace routing which I came across the other night.  This kind of works for me so will post until someone comes up with better.

Answer (score 0):

From the section Mads provided about controller routes ([see here - customise routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#using-application-model-to-customize-attribute-routes))

### NamespaceRoutingConvention.cs

```
public class NamespaceRoutingConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    private readonly string _baseNamespace;

    public NamespaceRoutingConvention(string baseNamespace)
    {
        _baseNamespace = baseNamespace;
    }

    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        var hasRouteAttributes = controller.Selectors.Any(selector =>
            selector.AttributeRouteModel != null);
        if (hasRouteAttributes)
        {
            // This controller manually defined some routes, so treat this 
            // as an override and not apply the convention here.
            return;
        }

        // Use the namespace and controller name to infer a route for the controller.
        //
        // Example:
        //
        //  controller.ControllerTypeInfo ->    "My.Application.Admin.UsersController"
        //  baseNamespace ->                    "My.Application"
        //
        //  template =>                         "Admin/[controller]"
        //
        // This makes your routes roughly line up with the folder structure of your project.
        //
        if (controller.ControllerType.Namespace == null)
            return;

        var template = new StringBuilder(GetControllerNamespace(controller.ControllerType.Namespace));

        template.Replace('.', '/');
        template.Append("/[controller]");

        foreach (var selector in controller.Selectors)
        {
            selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel()
            {
                Template = template.ToString()
            };
        }
    }

    private string GetControllerNamespace(string controllerNamespace)
    {
        return controllerNamespace == _baseNamespace
            ? ""
            : controllerNamespace.Substring(
                _baseNamespace.Length + 1,
                controllerNamespace.Length -
                _baseNamespace.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options => 
        options.Conventions.Add(new NamespaceRoutingConvention("Enter the route namespace of the api folder")))
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
 }
```

### api Folder Structure

Under the API folder, I now have the following structure:

```
/api
  /Ploop
    HelloController.cs
  HelloController.cs
  TestController.cs
```

### Sample Controller Code

So each controller code looks like the following:

```
public class HelloController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Index()
    {
        return new JsonResult(new
        {
            message = "hello from XXX controller"
        });
    }

    [HttpGet("{id?}")]
    public JsonResult Index(int? id)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new
        {
            message = "Hello from XXX controller with index",
            id
        });
    }
}
```

### Calling Controllers

So when we call each controller we get the following outputs in the browser:

#### api/Ploop/HelloController.cs

http://localhost:51248/Ploop/Hello

```
{"message":"Hello from Ploop HelloController"}
```

http://localhost:51248/Ploop/Hello/12

```
{"message":"Hello from Ploop HelloController with index","id":12}
```

#### api/HelloController.cs

http://localhost:51248/Hello

```
{"message":"Hello from root HelloController"}
```

http://localhost:51248/Hello/12

```
{"message":"Hello from root HelloController with index","id":12}
```

#### api/TestController.cs

http://localhost:51248/Test

```
{"message":"Hello from TestController"}
```

http://localhost:51248/Test/12

```
{"message":"Hello from TestController with index","id":12}
```